# net7mma rtsp stream format

Tags: c#, stream, format, rtsp

I would like to make an rtsp stream in c# with net7mma nuggets and I have the 
 following code:

```
static RtspServer szerver = new RtspServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8554)
    {
        Logger = new RtspServerConsoleLogger()
    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var source = new Media.Rtsp.Server.MediaTypes.MJPEGMedia("stream",new Uri(@"D:\*\*\*.mkv"));
        source.ForceTCP = true;
        szerver.TryAddMedia(source);
        szerver.Start();

    }
```

with this usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Media.Rtsp;
using Media.Rtsp.Server;
```

The problem is when I would like to test it in VLC or in SMplayer they say the fileformat is unknown, can someone help me? I red a lot about this but there is almost nothing what helps me.

cheers

Comment: any logger output? are the asterisks in your Uri just you masking the actual values, or is that actually used? mkv opens locally?

Comment: They are just maskin, there are some actual values there. Yes I can open that file any time and I can even stream it with VLC but I don't know why my code is not working as good as it should

Comment: not sure if MJPEGMedia can take a local physical path as the source and successfully read from that. the [source code](https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma/blob/38015e9796475f2c48f4afe36a9d46ed2b1ceb9b/RtspServer/MediaTypes/MJPEGMedia.cs#L577) suggests that if it errors, it just keeps waiting. could you source-level include the net7mma library and debug it to see what's going on?